# Unable to take full screen screenshots "Your screenshot can't be saved"

Tags: macos, catalina, screen-capture

I'm currently on Catalina 10.15.4 and recently started seeing a popup whenever I try to take full screen screenshots. A window pops up saying "Your screenshot can't be saved. Unable to capture window image." I've tried to capture via the grab tool and also pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd> then and then clicking.

I've tried changing the default directory that my screenshots are saved to from the desktop to a folder called screenshots but this didn't help.
`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Screnshots`.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Does the directory `~/Screenshots` exist?  It's not a directory that exists by default.

Comment: @Allan I don't think it matters? If the screencapture location doesn't exist, the file will just be saved to the Desktop instead (under normal conditions).

Comment: Try creating a new user account. Does the screenshot tool work in the new user account?

Comment: @Nic, does it?  Why would it "know" to default somewhere else?

Comment: @Allan - On 10.15.4 it does default to `~/Desktop` if `~/Screnshots` (or whatever location you set) does not exist.  It also defaults to `~/Desktop` if  location is not set at all which it isn't by default - the initial result of `defaults read com.apple.screencapture location` is *"The domain/default pair of (com.apple.screencapture, location) does not exist"*.

Comment: @Allan @Nic Thanks, yes `~/Screenshots` does exist-- I created it as a test to see if there was perhaps a permissions issue. I set the folder to full access `777` but that still didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @Nic Thanks for the suggestion, It does in fact work when I create a new account, and will work for a period of time in my primary user account for a little while after restarting, then at some point I receive that error again.

Answer (score 1):

Does your Mac have a Touch Bar? If so, check the location shown there after you press Cmd + Shift + 4. Is it a valid folder?